# Change opacity in picturebox

Tags: vb.net, opacity, picturebox

I use this function

```
Public Shared Function ChangeOpacity(ByVal img As Image, ByVal opacityvalue As Single) As Bitmap
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height)
  Dim graphics__1 As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
  Dim colormatrix As New colormatrix
        colormatrix.Matrix33 = opacityvalue
        Dim imgAttribute As New ImageAttributes
        imgAttribute.SetColorMatrix(colormatrix, ColorMatrixFlag.[Default], ColorAdjustType.Bitmap)
        graphics__1.DrawImage(img, New Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height, _
         GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgAttribute)
        graphics__1.Dispose()
    Return bmp
End Function
```

I use this command

picturebox.Image = ChangeOpacity(picturebox.Image, 0.3)

This is work ,The picturebox's opacity is fade out.
but when I try this

picturebox.Image = ChangeOpacity(picturebox.Image, 1.0)

It is nothing happen , The picture is still fade out I want to return picture into default
How to fix this ? 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the image form file like this

```
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Documents and 
Settings\User3\Desktop\Sathish\image\calendar-icon-reportdate.png")
```

And use the call opacity like this

```
 PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()
 PictureBox1.Image = ChangeOpacity(Image.FromFile("C:\Documents and
 Settings\User3\Desktop\Sathish\image\calendar-icon-reportdate.png"), 0.3)



 PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()
 PictureBox1.Image = ChangeOpacity(Image.FromFile("C:\Documents and
 Settings\User3\Desktop\Sathish\image\calendar-icon-reportdate.png"), 1)
```

Comment: When you change images in a PictureBox, you need to make sure to call `Dispose` on the old images!

Comment: @CodyGray Now check it sir. Its Correct?

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter in `ChangeOpacity()` function is the Opacity Percentage or factor of the picture in first parameter.

So (1.0) will not change the Opacity, it will return the picture without changes.

You have to multiply the previous opacity value to have (1) and return the picture into default OR reload your image from the source with the default opacity to first parameter.

In your example 
The_Current_Opacity * Opacity_Factor = 1

0.3 * Opacity_Factor = 1

use: `picturebox.Image = ChangeOpacity(picturebox.Image, 3.3)`

I prefer the division `(1/0.3)`. It's more accurate than `( 3.3)`.

Here is the code and you can do the math

```
dim OpacityPercentage as Single 
OpacityPercentage = 0.3

'To fade out the picturebox's opacity
picturebox1.Image = ChangeOpacity(picturebox1.Image, OpacityPercentage )

'To return picture into default
picturebox1.Image = ChangeOpacity(picturebox1.Image, 1/OpacityPercentage )
```